# Installed python-mode; now I only see class names in my file

Tags: python, vim, python-mode

I installed python-mode for vim on my Mac OSX system. I decided to try one of the python motion commands. I hit [C which I thought would go to the next class. But the screen also switched, to show ONLY class names in gray highlighting. I've searched the python-mode documentation, and I can't see anything about this happening, and therefore no way to undo it.

Well, I thought, I will just quit and reload, and everything will be fine. But no! When I come back in to the file, it opens as I left it, with just the class names showing, highlighted in gray, and indications of line numbers.

How do I get out of this "mode" or whatever I am stuck in?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've discovered the "folding" feature of Vim. Press `zo` to open one fold under the cursor. `zO` opens all folds under the cursor. `zv` opens just enough folds to see the cursor line. `zR` opens all folds. See `:help folding` for details.

Comment: By the way, how does vim "remember" that I was viewing the file "folded," so that when I restart it is still folded?

Comment: Oh, once python-mode is installed, every file seems to open this way!

Comment: That makes more sense now. By default if folds are defined, Vim will open the file with all of them closed. There is a foldlevelstart option that can help, or you can use autocmds, to [open all folds when editing a file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with folding, you might like to disable `python-mode` folding by keeping `let g:pymode_folding = 0` in `~/.vimrc`.

What I usually do is `enable` folding and use `space bar` to open it. I also set `set foldclose=all` to automatically fold unfolded fold